Logstash doesn't write logs via UDP
Configuration in logback-spring.xml:
<springProfile name="logstash">
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashUdpSocketAppender">
      <host>my-release-logstash</host>
      <port>8084</port>

      <layout class="net.logstash.logback.layout.LogstashLayout">
        <customFields>{"k8s_namespace":"${k8sNamespace}","k8s_pod":"${k8sPod}","k8s_node":"${k8sNode}"}</customFields>
      </layout>

    </appender>
  </springProfile>

Description of my-release-logstash Service:
Name:              my-release-logstash
Namespace:         default
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-release,app.kubernetes.io/name=logstash
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.99.21.114
IPs:               10.99.21.114
Port:              http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.129:8080
Port:              udp  8084/UDP
TargetPort:        udp/UDP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.129:8084

Description of my-release-logstash StatefulSet:
Name:               my-release-logstash
Namespace:          default
Pod Template:
  Service Account:  my-release-logstash
  Containers:
   logstash:
    Image:           docker.io/bitnami/logstash:8.15.1-debian-12-r0
    Ports:           8080/TCP, 9600/TCP, 8084/UDP
    Host Ports:      0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/UDP
    SeccompProfile:  RuntimeDefault
........


Description of my-release-logstash ConfigMap:
Name:         my-release-logstash
Namespace:    default

Data
====
logstash.conf:
----
input {
  udp {
  port => 8084
   type => syslog
 codec => json
 }
  tcp {
  port => 8080
  type => syslog
 codec => json
 }
  http { port => 8080 }
  
}
output {
 stdout {}
}


It works when I configure it via TCP:
<springProfile name="logstash">
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
      <destination>my-release-logstash:8080</destination>

      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <customFields>{"k8s_namespace":"${k8sNamespace}","k8s_pod":"${k8sPod}","k8s_node":"${k8sNode}"}</customFields>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
  </springProfile>

But doesn't send anything via UDP. What am I missing?
(Most of the descriptions were removed due to 'your post is mostly code' error. )
